# Azure DevOps for WINDEV application (PCSOFT ) with HFSQL database

Tags: azure-devops, devops, windev

Once we deploy WINDEV on Azure VM , does WINDEV application support deployment via Azure DevOps.

In the tag line of WINDEV 25, they mention that DevOps is supported , but i dont know which DevOps.

Please help

Comment: I didnot find any existing tasks to build or deploy windev applications in azure devops. But there are many tasks to connect and deploy to azure resources from azure devops. Since there is not a build task existing for windev application. You can check if it can be done by command lines. Or you can generate  a deployment package locally and try deploying using azure devops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure DevOps does not have any Out-of-box templates for WINDEV (PCSOFT) applications.  We will have to create custom templates to achieve the same.